# Adding/Removing "XP" based on messages sent in a certain time frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

People are spamming channels to gain "XP" (I've used dollars instead) and I was trying to add XP (dollars) if the user doesn't spam, but remove a bit more if they spam the channel. Right now the code is adding dollars, but it seems to be adding +2 dollars each time and not removing dollars if the user spams the channel. I used `if not message.author.id == "111176943920152603":` to make sure it's the user and not the bot

```
client = discord.Client()

user_timer = {}
user_spam_count = {}
rdollars = random.randint(0,3)

def save_cash():
with open("cash.json", "w+") as fp:
    json.dump(cash, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_dollars(user: discord.User, dollars: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars"] = cash[id].get("dollars", 0) + dollars
    print("{} now has {} dollars".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars"]))
    save_cash()

def remove_dollars(user: discord.User, dollars: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars"] = cash[id].get("dollars", 0) - dollars
    print("{} now has {} dollars".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars"]))
    save_cash()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.id == "111176943920152603":
    user_timer[message.author.id] = time.time()
            try:
                if time.time() >= user_timer[message.author.id] + 2:
                    user_spam_count[message.author.id] = 0
                    add_dollars(message.author, rdollars)

                if time.time() < user_timer[message.author.id] + 2:
                    user_spam_count[message.author.id] += 1
                    if user_spam_count[message.author] >= 4:
                        remove_dollars(message.author, 25)
                    if user_spam_count[message.author.id] >= 10:
                        remove_dollars(message.author, 50)

            except KeyError:
                add_dollars(message.author, rdollars)
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? I don't see where the `save_cash` function is defined. I also cannot see where `user_timer` is updated, as it only seems to be part of your `if` statements.

Comment: Oops, i did forget the user_timer code, i didn't add the "save_cash()" because I wasn't trying to spam the question with code lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `.id` in

```
if user_spam_count[message.author] >= 4:
    remove_dollars(message.author, 25)
```

This

```
if user_spam_count[message.author.id] >= 4:
    remove_dollars(meesage.author,25)
```

should work fine

It kept catching a KeyError because of this and adding money instead of going inside the if statement and removing it

This should fix time issue you were having:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if not message.author.id == "111176943920152603":
    try:
      last_post_time = user_timer[message.author.id]
      user_timer[message.author.id] = time.time()

      if user_timer[message.author.id] - last_post_time >= 2:
        user_spam_count[message.author.id] = 0
        add_dollars(message.author, rdollars)

      elif user_timer[message.author.id] - last_post_time < 2:
        user_spam_count[message.author.id] += 1
        if user_spam_count[message.author.id] >= 4:
          remove_dollars(message.author, 25)
        elif user_spam_count[message.author.id] >= 10:
          remove_dollars(message.author, 50)
        else:
          add_dollars(message.author, rdollars)

    except KeyError:
      user_timer[message.author.id] = time.time()
      user_spam_count[message.author.id]=0
      print(user_timer)
      add_dollars(message.author, rdollars)
```

The way to detect if someone sent a message in a certain timeframe after their last message is to check if the current_time_of_message - time_of_last_message < desired_amount_of_time

- The current_time_of_message is time.time()
- The time_of_last_message is the value in your {userID:time}
  dictionary
- The desired amount is the amount of time it has to pass between 2
  messages before they're not considered spam anymore

In this case, you've set it to 2 and I've left it as is

You kept checking based on the same value (You would set your dictionary time to time.time() and compare it to time.time() 2 lines below it)
Instead, it's better to store that value in a variable and compare using if/elif

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I added .id to `user_spam_count[message.author.id] >=4:` but now it seems like everytime I send a message, it adds 3 dollars. When I spam, it doesn't remove any dollars at all either.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution! It makes sense now I've tested it for an hour now. `time.time()` counts by seconds correct? I've ran into another issue where it will add_dollars for the first message the user sends but any message after that it doesn't count as XP, it only keeps adding messages until the user reaches the user_spam_count and then starts to deduct XP instead of adding XP each time the user sends a message without hitting the user_spam_count.

Comment: I've edited the code above and fixed that problem now.  
Here is the documentation for `time.time()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time

Comment: Thank you! This works flawlessly now. I appreciate all of your knowledge and help.